# Submitting to Apple: XCode "submit" or Application Loader?

Tags: ios, xcode

iTunes Connect says to use the Application Loader utility in the Mac Developer Utilities folder.

There is also the XCode Submit feature in the Archive area, the same place where you validate an app before submission.

Do these two utilities do the same thing? Which is preferable?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

They do the same thing. The only difference is that the Application loader forces you to validate the binary beforehand, whereas in Xcode 4, it's a separate button.

I recommend using the Xcode "Submit" button, especially if you're using Xcode 4. The way Apple redesigned Xcode 4 from Xcode 3, it looks as though they want people to use it. (They made it easier in Xcode 4.) Doing so will eliminate an extra tool from your workflow and might just make your life a little simpler.

Just note the process when using Xcode 4. If you're doing Ad Hoc builds, you'll need a second scheme to Archive those with proper code signing. If you're just doing local builds, you'll be fine with just one scheme.

Be sure to use the notes section in Xcode 4's Archives (area?) to note which builds are Ad Hoc and which are for the App Store. Also, in Xcode (not sure about the Application Loader), when submitting, you'll be prompted to select a code signing certificate. Make sure this selection matches what what you actually signed with.

With these things in mind, they are essentially the same.

Comment: My Archive scheme is set to Distribution, and uses an ad-hoc provisioning profile. I used Validate in Xcode 4 by selecting the Distribution rather than Developing profiles and it worked for validation; I had a code-signing error unless I used the Distribution profile. If I'm submitting to the Apple Store, does it matter if I use the ad-hoc distribution profile, the one that works in validation?

Comment: What's strange is that my Release scheme is set to Developer, not Distribution, but Validate only worked with the ad-hoc profile....Even when I switched the Archive scheme to Developer.

Comment: You need to create a second scheme and modify the "Archive" action to use an App Store certificate. Then, by switching between schemes you can have the Archive action build with different certificates. You can't interchange Ad Hoc and App Store certificates.

Comment: You also need to check that the proper certificates are being used. You do that in your "Build Settings".

Comment: It appears as though the Build Settings, Release, Distribution and they all show a matched certificate. However, even when my Archive is set to "Release" which is in turn set to a Developer Certificate, it still cannot validate, it provides a code-signing error. Yet, the certificate is of course from my Apple Dev account... are the App Store certificates different than the developer certificates?

Comment: Yes, you need to create a separate distribution certificate.

Comment: ok, final question: is the App Store "distribution" certificate different than our existing distribution certificate for Ad-Hoc that we already linked up. In other words, if I can Validate fine in Xcode, then I assume whatever method I used for that validation should work when I Submit; and I validated using the ad-hoc certficate.

Comment: No, Ad Hoc is not going to work for the App Store. Go into the portal and create a new one for the App Store.  The Ad Hoc certificate contains UDIDs whereas the App Store certificate does not.

Comment: pretty sure I got it all working, thanks for all the help. this provisioning and certificate stuff is about as complicated as just learning to program the language it self. :) The one point that doesn't make sense is why setup another Scheme; seems like all you really need to do is just edit the current Scheme's Archive Build Configuration to something else, like Release, rather than switch to a different Scheme altogether; same time and effort either way. If Release is set to your App Store certificate, it would work, I'd think.

Comment: Or, instead of that, just change the Distribution certificate in the Projects settings from one certificate to another. You are just swapping items in drop-down menus no matter which of these methods you use, but in the end everything builds the same, right?

Comment: @andrewjs - Correct. I suggest keeping two schemes for easier switching between the two.